# Sorting table hierarchical while considering conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting

I have a PostgreSQL Table and want to order it hierarchical with cases. Here is an example:

```
> Name    |    Port
> ----------------------------  
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet2/2 
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/2
> Switch2 | 1.23
> Switch2 | 1.21
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet2/1
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/1/3
> Switch1 | FastEthernet1/1/14 
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/19
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/20
> Switch2 | Port-Channel3 
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/0/4
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/1/3
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/2
> Switch2 | 1.14
> Switch2 | Port-Channel6
```

After ordering/ sorting it should be like that:

```
> Name    |    Port
> ----------------------------  
> Switch1 | FastEthernet1/1/14 
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/2
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/19
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/20
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/2
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet2/1
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet2/2 
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/1/3
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/0/4
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/1/3
> Switch2 | 1.14
> Switch2 | 1.21
> Switch2 | 1.23
> Switch2 | Port-Channel3 
> Switch2 | Port-Channel6
```

I have tried to do something with ORDER BY CASE. Here is an example:

```
SELECT device.name, device_port.port
   FROM device
   JOIN device_port ON device.ip = device_port.ip
   ORDER BY CASE WHEN device_port.port like 'Fast%' THEN string_to_array(substr(device_port.port, position('/' in device_port.port)-1 ),'/')::float[] 
         WHEN device_port.port like 'Gigabit%' THEN string_to_array(substr(device_port.port,16),'/')::float[] 
         WHEN device_port.port like 'Port-channel%' THEN string_to_array(substr(device_port.port,13),'/')::float[] END;
```

But in this way there is no possibility to order it first by device.name and by name of the port. The result would be for example like:

```
> Name    |    Port
> ----------------------------  
> Switch1 | FastEthernet1/1/14
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/2
> Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/2
> Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/0/4
```

And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html).

In the example I use one table for simplicity and select `port_name` and `port_number` for a better understanding.

```
select 
    *, 
    regexp_replace(port, '[0-9/\.]', '', 'g') port_name,
    string_to_array(regexp_replace(port, '[A-Za-z\-]', '', 'g'), '/')::float[] port_number
from 
    device
order by 
    name, 
    regexp_replace(port, '[0-9/\.]', '', 'g'),
    string_to_array(regexp_replace(port, '[A-Za-z\-]', '', 'g'), '/')::float[];

  name   |         port         |    port_name    | port_number 
---------+----------------------+-----------------+-------------
 Switch1 | FastEthernet1/1/14   | FastEthernet    | {1,1,14}
 Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/2    | FastEthernet    | {3,0,2}
 Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/19   | FastEthernet    | {3,0,19}
 Switch1 | FastEthernet3/0/20   | FastEthernet    | {3,0,20}
 Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/1/3 | GigabitEthernet | {1,1,3}
 Switch1 | GigabitEthernet1/2   | GigabitEthernet | {1,2}
 Switch1 | GigabitEthernet2/1   | GigabitEthernet | {2,1}
 Switch1 | GigabitEthernet2/2   | GigabitEthernet | {2,2}
 Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/0/4 | GigabitEthernet | {3,0,4}
 Switch1 | GigabitEthernet3/1/3 | GigabitEthernet | {3,1,3}
 Switch2 | 1.14                 |                 | {1.14}
 Switch2 | 1.21                 |                 | {1.21}
 Switch2 | 1.23                 |                 | {1.23}
 Switch2 | Port-Channel3        | Port-Channel    | {3}
 Switch2 | Port-Channel6        | Port-Channel    | {6}
(15 rows)
```

**Option with `int[]`.**

I thought you had used the type `float[]` intentionally. If you want to compare `int[]` values (and convert a float number to an int array) you can use [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) on the fly:

```
select 
    *, 
    regexp_replace(port, '[0-9/\.]', '', 'g') port_name,
    string_to_array(
        regexp_replace(
            translate(port, '.', '/'),
            '[A-Za-z\-]', '', 'g'),
        '/')::int[] port_number
from 
    device
order by 
    name, 
    regexp_replace(port, '[0-9/\.]', '', 'g'),
    string_to_array(
        regexp_replace(
            translate(port, '.', '/'),
            '[A-Za-z\-]', '', 'g'),
        '/')::int[];

  name   | port | port_name | port_number 
---------+------+-----------+-------------
 Switch2 | 1.1  |           | {1,1}
 Switch2 | 1.2  |           | {1,2}
 Switch2 | 1.14 |           | {1,14}
 Switch2 | 1.21 |           | {1,21}
 Switch2 | 1.23 |           | {1,23}
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

@klin: Wow such a simple code and nearly works as expected! Thank's a lot! Didn't know that such regular expression functions are existing.

The only thing that lacks is the separation of {1.14} into an array like {1,14}.

Currently the sorting fails for example in such a situation:

```
> Name    |    Port
> ------------------
> Switch2 | 1.1
> Switch2 | 1.18
> Switch2 | 1.19
> Switch2 | 1.2
> Switch2 | 1.20
> Switch2 | 1.21
```

But should be like

```
> Name    |    Port
> ------------------
> Switch2 | 1.1
> Switch2 | 1.2
> Switch2 | 1.18
> Switch2 | 1.19
> Switch2 | 1.20
> Switch2 | 1.21
```

I think the solution should be something like that:

```
order by 
    name, 
    regexp_replace(port, '[0-9/\.]', '', 'g'),
    string_to_array(regexp_replace(port, '[A-Za-z\-]', '', 'g'), '/')::float[],
    string_to_array(regexp_matches(port, '**finding a . in the string**', **give back full string matching pattern** , 'g'), '.')::float[];
```

Questions:

1) Could you help me building this regexp_matches function so that it returns the full string always when it finds a dot?

2) What does the '' in your regexp replace expression mean? It should usually give the replacement pattern.

Again thanks for your help!

Comment: See the edited answer. The empty string in `regexp_replace(port, '[0-9/\.]', '', 'g')` means that all tokens that match `'[0-9/\.]`' are removed from `port`.

Comment: Ok this seems to be the easier solution. Now everything works as expected. I appreciate your support!